# ¿Como puedo dejar un div fijo en un slider, sin que se mueva con este?

Tags: css, div, slider

Hola estoy tratando de que mi div que esta sobre el cada imagen, sobre el slider nose mueva con el. Se que tiene que ver con la position:relative o absolute.Pero no he podido. Agadeceria cualquier ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Me falto una imagen de los estilos css. Para complementar mi pregunta. Disculpas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antes que nada, ¡Bienvenido(a) a SOes!. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Hola, por favor, completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio (y de ese modo ganar tu primera medalla). Luego edita la pregunta para añadir el código en modo texto (las imágenes pueden no verse para otros usuarios) y, a ser posible, un ejemplo ejecutable en la propia pregunta (lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve])

Comment: Slider debe tener 2 hijos, un slider-container y otro un slider-footer (por llamarlo de alguna manera). En slider-container poner las images-container, y en slider-footer poner el texto, Slider debes tener declarada su position y silder-footer le pones position absolute

Comment: Ese slider footer del que hablas en mi codigo está como cov. En este tengo el h1 y el p